# Microsoft Word mergefield token polish currency formatting

Tags: word-2013, mergefield

I want to Format number from `1,234.25` to `1 234,25`. I tried below mergefield formatting but it did not gave the expected result `{MergeField token \# "# ###,##"}`. I have been googling whole day but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

You could do some math to re-format your output.

For example, you want "token" formatted to: **zł100,01** from **100.01**

Try the following

**zł{= INT({MERGEFIELD token})},{=INT({MERGEFIELD token}*100) - INT({MERGEFIELD token})*100)**

Above, you can see how to calculate the integer portion and the fractional portions separately and manually placing a "," between them.

**NOTE:** **{=}** should be entered as a mail merge field similar to **{ MERGEFIELD }**

Cheers,
Kevin